# How to disable server side validation of nested form in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have given server side validation of nested form. each of that having model and in that given server side validation.
But, main of that form of in model server side validation working of at the time of save, which i have disabled it.
but, also i have disabled nested forms model server side validation, but it is not working.

```
 validates_presence_of   :user_mob, :message => 'please enter the mobile number.' ,unless: :skip_valid
    validates_presence_of   :address, :message => 'please enter the address.', unless: :skip_valid
```

//this is main model

class UserDetails< ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :u_user_details, :foreign_key => 'u_id'

```
validates_presence_of :year, :message => 'please enter the details.', unless: :skip_valid
validates_presence_of :user_name, :message => 'please enter the details.', unless: :skip_valid
validates_presence_of :user_address, :message => 'please enter the details.', unless: :skip_valid
validates_presence_of :user_mobile, :message => 'please enter the details.', unless: :skip_valid
validates_presence_of :user_type, :message => 'please enter the details.', unless: :skip_valid
```

end

Even I am giving unless: skip_valid in netsted forms model. it is not working.
how to disable nested forms model server side validation.

Comment: The easiest way to skip validation is to call `save(false)` the false indicates that you do not want to run validations

Comment: Also I am giving skip validation false at the time of save, till not yet working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

validates_presence_of :year, :message => 'please enter the details.', if: ->(u) { u.commit == 'submit' or u.commit == 'approve' or u.commit == 'reapply'}

We can do it like this.